# Как разобрать инфинитив по составу?

Tags: морфемика

Инфинитив считается  начальной формой глагола, поэтому кажется естественным, что от него образуются остальные глагольные формы. **Но так ли это?**

**У глагола выделяется две основы:** основа настоящего времени и основа прошедшего времени, например: чита/л и чита/ет, но: пис/а/л и пиш/ет. Из этих примеров видно, что основы могут совпадать, но могут и различаться. (По соотношению основ глаголы делятся на классы и группы).

**Морфемный состав инфинитива должен сравниваться с этими основами.** Рассмотрим проблемные глаголы с формантами ЧЬ и СТИ.

1) Глаголы ***печь, беречь***: пёк/берёг, печёт/бережёт. Глаголы с основой на задненёбные К и Г образуют инфинитив от основы **без этих согласных** посредством **суффикса ЧЬ**, то есть происходит усечение основы и добавляется суффикс ЧЬ: ***пе/чь, бере/чь.***

2) Глаголы ***гре/сти, ве/зти, ле/зть, бре/сти, па/сти*** (основа на Б, С, З): грёб/гребёт, нёс/несёт, вёз/везёт, лез/лезет.  Также от основы без конечной согласной образуется инфинитив у глаголов с основой прош. и наст. вр. на согласные Б,С,З. Суффикс инфинитива СТИ/СТЬ (ЗТИ/ЗТЬ).

http://rus.1september.ru/article.php?id=200404404

**И вопросы:**

Личная форма глагола образуется от инфинитива или наоборот (при школьном разборе)?

Как делается обычный школьный разбор для глаголов ***беречь, нести, везти, пасти?***

Входят ли  суффиксы **-ЧЬ, -СТИ** в основу и почему входят или не входят?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В большинстве учебных пособий у глагола выделяются две основы: **основа
инфинитива и основа настоящего времени.**

> От основы неопределенной формы образуются: прошедшее время, причастие прошедшего времени (действительное и страдательное) и деепричастие совершенного вида: **возненавиде-ть, возненавиде-л, возненавиде-вший, возненавиде-нный, возненавиде-в.**

От основы настоящего времени образуются формы настоящего или будущего простого, повелительного наклонения, причастия настоящего времени (действительное и страдательное) и деепричастия несовершенного вида: называj-ут (называют), **называй, называj-ущий (называющий), называj-емый (называемый), называj-а (называя).**

*Некоторые глаголы имеют три основы* **(учебник Шанский, Тихонов):** ин­финитива, настоящего времени и **прошедшего времени,** так как основы инфинитива и прошедшего времени у них не совпадают **(тере-ть — тер — тр-ут; мокнуть — мок — мокнут и др.).**
В таких случаях у ряда глаголов образуются параллельные формы: **мок,** **мокнул, мокший   мокнувший и т. д. (т. е. формы образуются и от основы инфинитива, и от основы прошедшего времени)**.

По поводу глаголов, которые заканчиваются на "чь". В современной лингвистике принято, что "чь" — это и часть корня, и нулевой формообразующий суффикс, т.е. наблюдается наложение морфем.
[(См.: Е. И. Литневская. Русский язык: краткий теоретический курс для школьников)](http://www.gramota.ru/book/litnevskaya.php?part2.htm#3_5)
Ср.: беречь, береги, берегу, бережёшь (г//ж//ч).
Что касается суффикса **сти**, следует отметить, что не все лингвисты выделяют его в глаголе. См. напр. у Литневской: плес-ти, где **-ти** — формообразующий суффикс.

Но в любом случае **сти** не входит в состав корня.

Comment: Извините, но я позволила себе "поправить" Ваш ответ.

Comment: @– Римма Михайлова, спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Несколько ранее вы уже отметили, что нет единого мнения о –ть, -ти, -сти, -чь в глаголах, поэтому в школе все зависит от авторов выбранной программы и учебника. Если взять самый распространенный УМК (учебно-методический комплекс) Т.А. Ладыженской, М.Т. Баранова и др., то в учебнике будет сказано, что:

1.личная форма глагола образуется от инфинитива;

3.-чь входит в состав корня, а –ть и –ти являются окончаниями неопределенной формы глагола; вопрос «почему» подробно не освещается.
В учебнике 5 класса есть таблица чередований, в которой в т.ч. указано и чередование г/к/ч/ц, что дает основание относить –чь к корню (беречь – берег, печь – пек и пр.).

А про –ть и –ти сказано, что это окончания, перед которыми находится суффикс – показатель спряжения. Предполагается, что –ть и –ти вполне вписываются в определение окончания как изменяемой части слова, образующей формы слова.

2. Соответственно в глаголе ***беречь*** нулевое окончание; все слово является корнем.
   В состав остальных слов входит корень и окончание –ти.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.  В школе учат разным наукам, причем довольно сложным, но вот почему-то сложилось мнение, что именно родной русский язык надо давать как можно проще, примитивнее, хотя и неправильно, иначе дети не поймут. Отсюда следуют все проблемы.

Answer (score 0):

Нет единого мнения о морфемах неопределенной формы глаголов. Так что объяснение в разных учебниках дается по-разному, поэтому учеников надо предупреждать о том, что может быть иная трактовка этих морфем. В диагностических работах дается такая трактовка, по учебникам каких авторов занимаются ученики, сдающие диагностику. Но честно говоря, это путаница! Как-то нужно прийти к определенному мнению.